# GTK motion notify event, is_hint always true

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm new to GTK and am trying  Vala to get a feel. (I'm using gtk+3.0)

Can anyone explain why the event->is_hint always seems to return 1? From the docs I get the impression it's supposed to help cut-down excess motion events.

Here's a small Vala sample. The motion_notify_event handler never gets the chance to follow the else-clause.

Am I grokking this wrong, or making a stupid mistake or is this a GTK+3 thing that's not ready yet?

```vala
/* To compile: valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 appname.vala */

using Cairo;

namespace Demo {

public class Scribble : Gtk.DrawingArea {

  public Scribble () {
    this.add_events ( Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK | Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK );
    this.set_size_request (100,100);
  }

  private void draw_circ ( Cairo.Context cr ) {
      var y = get_allocated_height () / 2;
      var radius = double.min (get_allocated_width () / 2, get_allocated_height () / 2) - 5;
      cr.arc (y, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      cr.set_source_rgb (1, 1, 1);
      cr.fill_preserve ();
      cr.set_source_rgb (0, 0, 0);
      cr.stroke ();
  }

  public override bool draw ( Cairo.Context cr ) {
      this.draw_circ ( cr);
      return false;
  }

  public override bool motion_notify_event (Gdk.EventMotion event ) {
    //Seems event.is_hint is *always* 1
    //stdout.printf ( "is_hint: %d\n", event.is_hint );

    if (event.is_hint == 1) {
      stdout.printf ( "is hint\n" );
      Gdk.Event.request_motions(event); //Always 1, so what's the point?
    } else {
      //Never gets here. Why?
      stdout.printf ( "normal motion at: %G, %G\n", event.x, event.y );
    }
    return true; //false does not change anything either.
  }

}
}

int main ( string[] args ) {
  Gtk.init ( ref args );
  var window = new Gtk.Window ();
  var scribble = new Demo.Scribble ();

  window.add (scribble);
  window.show_all ();
  window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

  Gtk.main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I didn't really answer your queries in the response. Regarding the number of events, how are you exactly calculating? How are you repeating same set of motion events with and without hint mask? Regarding `is_hint` being set to `TRUE` whenever the mask is set, I have made the same observation with your sample run a few time (not really concrete evidence that its always the case). In the source code, [this](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/gdkwindow.c#n9613) is only place I could find where the `is_hint` is set to `TRUE`. The only case in which case this is not set to `TRUE`

Comment: .. when you use the hint mask is when the [device](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/gdkwindow.c#n9407) is not found in the hash table `display->motion_hint_info`. This does not seem to be the case i.e. the device for the event (the mouse probably) is in the list (which is [added when you set the event](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/gdkwindow.c#n5914)). I hope you could make some sense out the text

Comment: I am putting together bits of code along a road towards a vector drawing app. There is going to be a lot of looking for hits under the mouse soon and that will slow the motion handler.  

I'm not hell-bent on this hint stuff, I just thought there was a "Right Way" (TM) to do motion event, I read the docs and found some sample code (scribble demo in gtk2) and here I am.  

Thanks for testing my code. I'm glad you also found (what seems to be) a constant is_hint == 1 situation. At least it's a general finding.  

Many thanks @another.anon.coward thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly about `is_hint` (I can't comment) but if you want to cut down motion notifications, consider using [`idle_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add).

It can be used to process motion events after there are no longer motion events.

Answer (score 1):

When you set GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK
=> you receive every mouse moove

When you set GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK
=> you are supposed to receive less motion event
=> any part of your app can trigger a motion event by calling gdk_window_get_pointer().

when you set both you abort the benefits from receiving less motion hint

try to add some counter in the motion event callback to measure the difference
http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gdk/gdk-Events.html#GdkEventMask

Comment: I just tried it with **only** the GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK in add_events -- now my handler receives no motion events at all.